# Abstracted GUI Design Model

Tags: user-interface, graphics, coding-style

I am developing a front end GUI that people use to communicate with equipment that we manufacturer and sell.  Our equipment (black box) talks over ethernet to our GUI: reporting status, provides the user with controls to configure parameters within the black box, queries diagnostic data, etc.

The GUI needs to be used by engineering for debugging purposes in development of our black box, used in production to test the equipment against customer requirements, and used by the customer to interface with the black box at a high level.  The challenge is the engineering diagnostic GUI elements confuse the people using the GUI in production, and the customer wants a very streamlined, simple GUI which isn't of much help for engineering or production.

I don't want to design three separate GUI's as there is so much overlap between these programs at the lower-level, in addition, to creating a software configuration control nightmare.  Is there a model or strategy for designing a GUI for multiple applications or multiple end-users?  Any suggestions or best practices?

Answer (score 0):

User-centered design has several strategies for tackling this type of problem. The full-blown option is to use personas to determine how similar the needs of debuggers, testers and users are, and how many user groups you truly have. Personas are based on research with users. You can gather information by listening in on support calls or observing your engineers at work. Maybe you have three user groups with distinctly different goals, background, tech-savviness and needs, but maybe you only have two distinct groups, where testers and debuggers would be content with the same UI, but end-users would find it too technical and too confusing.

Knowing what you know about how your internal users work, you might be able to justify employing the UI design pattern "Extras On Demand". The strategy is to present by default a streamlined and simple UI that is relatively basic, with full functionality available one click away. Think of the difference between simple search and advanced search. Simple search is generally shown by default, with advanced search just a click away.

Determine which tasks are appropriate self-service tasks for end-users and design an interface that makes it easy to accomplish those self-service tasks. Use terminology that your end-users use on support calls. Put constraints on their input, so they can only enter valid values. Keep them out of trouble by loading default values.

You may find that your expert users find it annoying to click the "show me more" link, or you may find that they don't mind, because they use the simple UI for quick tasks and don't always go to the full-featured UI for every task.